# Removing Electrum completely

Tags: python, uninstall, python3

I installed the Electrum wallet on Ubuntu 16.04 through

```
sudo apt-get install python3-setuptools python3-pyqt5 python3-pip
sudo python3 -m pip install https://download.electrum.org/3.2.3/Electrum-3.2.3.tar.gz#egg=electrum[fast]
```

which is the default way shown on their website. It ran without trouble but when I tried to uninstall with

```
sudo pip uninstall electrum
```

it said

```
sudo: pip: command not found
```

I managed to get it to uninstall, probably, with

```
sudo python3 uninstall electrum
```

but I still get the icon in my dashboard, after `autoclean` `autoremove` and `reboot`. Clicking on it makes it *try* to load *something* and then fail but it makes me feel like I've missed something.

Any idea how to solve this? 
Ideally without a fresh install.

Comment: python3 -m pip unistall in this case

Answer (score 0):

You have tu use pip for uninstalling, apt won't work in that case. If it's not in your $PATH you can search for it, maye it's this one:  -:$ python3 /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip uninstall electrum